# Interface in BroadcastReceiver call only activity instead of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, broadcastreceiver

I've implemented a `custom interface` inside my `NetworkReceiver`

```
public interface onNetworkStateChanged {
    void onStateChange(int state);
}
```

I have set both of them on my Activity and Fragment

```
network = new NetworkReceiver();
network.setOnNetworkStateChanged(this);

---------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onStateChange(int state) {
    if (state == NetworkReceiver.STATE_ON) {
        networkState = state;
    } else {
        networkState = state;
    }
}
```

And when the NetworkReceiver is trigger, it's always the listener inside the Activity who will be called and never the one in the fragment

Anyone have a idea ? or i need to implement a customCallback inside my fragment who the activity will trigger to call the Fragment ?

EDIT :

i'v put this on the onStateChange on the Activity

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Utils.FEED_FRAGMENT);
if (f instanceof FeedFragment) {
    ((FeedFragment) f).onStateChange(state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, because your code is incomplete. You should register a Fragment as a listener, seems `setOnNetworkStateChanged(this)` uses Activity instance.

Or in the Activity you can find Fragment and directly call onStateChange(), so you'll get chained calls (same mechanics as onOptionsItemSelected).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think i will register my Fragment as a listener as you said and when the onStateChanged will be trigger i will call aswell the fragment listener for update my content :), Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
//create a public method setNetworkChageListner() inside NetworkReceiver

public void setNetworkChageListner(onNetworkStateChanged onNetwokChanged){
  this.onNetworkChanged=onNetworkChanged
}
/*check the global variable onNetworkChanged is null when you trigger the method onStateChange(int state)*/

//inside your fragment use receiver static variable of activity
netwok_receiver_static_variable.setNetworkChageListner(new NetworkReceiver.onNetworkStateChanged () {
            @Override
            public void onStateChange() {
                //do operation
            }
        })
```